# Autocommit OpenJPA writes

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I'm using OpenJPA and want to configure it to use Autocommit on every write/insert operation.

At the moment I have to do this:

```
        MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(e);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

What I want to be able to do is this:

```
MyEntity e = new MyEntity();        
em.persist(e); // auto commit here
```

I have this property set to true:

```
openjpa.NontransactionalWrite : true
```

Any clues?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't auto-commit with JPA. If you want to remove the local transaction management, use JTA/CMT or Spring managed transactions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, OpenJPA uses the autocommit value from the underlying connection. BUT it explicitly sets autocommit to false whenever you begin a transaction.

You can check the underlying connection with the following code:

```
OpenJPAEntityManager oem = OpenJPAPersistence.cast(em);
Connection conn = (Connection) oem.getConnection();
boolean autoCommit = conn.getAutoCommit();
```